# Principal not showing Authorities after implementing AuthoritiesExtractor

Tags: spring-security

I am extending AuthoritiesExtractor.  In my implementation I am adding a new authority called "MYROLE". I have created a bean (@Bean) as shown below in SecurityConfig.java to initialize this extractor as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public AuthoritiesExtractor userAuthorityExtractor() {
return new UserAuthorityExtractor();
}
```

My controller method /me returns the principal object shown below.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
@GetMapping("/me")
public Principal currentUser (Principal principal) {
return principal;
}
```

The returned object does not display the authority "MYROLE".  What am I missing?

Comment: I had similar issues... Posted my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894402/principalextractor-and-authoritiesextractor-are-not-getting-called/57626666#57626666. I don't want to double post the answer if it's not the solution. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, set a break point in your extractor. Does your code even execute? I would set the break point here:

```
@Bean
public AuthoritiesExtractor userAuthorityExtractor() {
    return new UserAuthorityExtractor();
}
```

If that's a no, then you need to figure out why your bean is not being invoked. I would make sure that your `SecurityConfig` is actually picked up by the [component scanner](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-component-scan).

As for your controller.

In Spring Security, there is no guarantee that the `Principal` object also holds the authorities. The principal itself is a very simple interface

```java
/**
 * Returns the name of this principal.
 *
 * @return the name of this principal.
 */
public String getName();
```

So what you want, is the `Authentication` object, because that interface exposes `getAuthorities`

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public Principal currentUser (Authentication authentication) {
        //do what you need with authorities
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        return authentication.getPrincipal();
    }
```

You can also review the default implementation

```java
public List<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Map<String, Object> map) {
    String authorities = "ROLE_USER";
    if (map.containsKey("authorities")) {
        authorities = this.asAuthorities(map.get("authorities"));
    }

    return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  For whatever reason, SpringBoot is not calling my extractor.  I have tried adding @Component to my Extractor, adding it as a bean as shown in the code, adding spring security libraries.  But nothing has helped so far

Comment: It depends on your package structure. A Spring Boot application will automatically scan the package the your `@SpringBootApplication` class is in and the sub packages. If your SecurityConfig is outside of this, try adding a `@ComponentScan`

Comment: I have complemented the answer above with some info on Spring Boot and @ComponentScan

Comment: It is a very simple project.  So far all classes in the same package.  Also security config is picked up since endpoint shows the restrictions I have defined. For example unauthenticated user can't access the /me endpoint.  For authenticated user it works fine.  Code snippet below
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test").hasRole("arcsso.test")
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("arcsso.admin")
        .antMatchers("/me").authenticated()
        .anyRequest()
        .permitAll()
}

Comment: The code is a little bit hard to read.I would supplement your question, and maybe link to a test project. There are two pieces that need to be put in place
1. The request needs to include a token, and 
2. the token needs to be parsed (token parsing configured)

If you post a small sample project, I can rework it for you.